# Supressing blank page after includepdf

Tags: pdfpages

I'm including a collection of manpages in the appendices of a thesis. I'm using

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

in the beginning of the document, and a number of lines like:

```
\includepdf{/myprog1.pdf}
\includepdf{/myprog2.pdf}
\includepdf{/myprog3.pdf}
```

in the appendix.

Using **pdflatex** the manual pages print correctly, but there is a blank page after the last manual page and the start of the next appendix.

How do I suppress that blank page?

Comment: Is the blank page part of `myprog3.pdf`?

Comment: This is not the normal behaviour unless it is part of the final PDF, of course.

Comment: Can you provide us more details in you MWE ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I went back and checked, all the included PDFs are single page documents.  If I print them, only one page comes out of the printer.  As a further detail, there is no blank page between them, only after the last one.  If I include only a single file, myprog1.pdf, then I still get a blank page at the end.  I'm sorry - I don't know what "MWE" refers to.

Comment: MWE = Minimal Working Example

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately never solved this particular problem.  Submitted the thesis with the offending blank page. Eventually got my PhD anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command before \includepdf

\let\clearpage\relax